# Links in line with text

Tags: html, css, text, hyperlink, inline

Can someone tell me how I can have text in line with five links please in my menu using html and css?

The current code is

```
<div class="menu content">
    <ul id="nav">
        <h1>JEWLLERY</h1>   
        <li><a href="">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Jewellery</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Locations</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Reviews</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- end of menu -->
```

I want the "JEWELLEY" to be on the left side with the links following, thanks.

The Content is in the menu bar at the top of my website.

I want the menu to appear as

JEWELLERY            HOME         Jewellery     Locations       Contact Us     Reviews

However at present the links (home, jewellery, locations, contact us, reviews) are displaying below "JEWELLERY"

Thanks.

Comment: Please elaborate. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. also @CTravel, I would say it's better to avoid float if there is another solution which is just as elegant (which would be simple `display: inline-block` on the list.

Answer (score 3):

Try `display` property

```
h1, li{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/U2PPu/)

Another Scenario
In this, you have to pick out `<h1>JEWLLERY</h1>` from the `<ul>`

```
h1{
    float:left; // can be replaced by display:inline-block; and vertical-align:top;
}
ul{
   display:inline-block;
}
```

**Updated Demo** `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/U2PPu/1/

*Note*: I'm using both `display:inline-block` and `float:left` property just to make you familier with both rules, otherwise `display:inline-block` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav
{
    list-style:none;
}
#nav li
{
    float:left;
}
```